# How to Get First Four Bytes of HMAC_SHA256(x,y)

Tags: php, byte, hmac

I'm implementing a ProvablyFair algorithm. One of the steps is to get the first four bytes of a hashed value as separate integers. How do I extract the bytes?

Here is what I've attempted:

```
<?php
    
    $ServerSeed = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    
    $ClientSeed ="3333";
    
    $Nonce="10";
    
    $Row_number = "1";
    
    $Data = "{$ClientSeed}:{$Nonce}:{$Row_number}:0";
    
    $Random = hash_hmac('sha256', $ServerSeed , $Data);
    
    $First4Bytes= mb_substr($Random, 0, 4);
```

How do I get the first four bytes of `$Random` as numbers `(e.g. [35, 33, 112, 121])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `binary` option in [hash_hmac](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) function to get a raw binary data, [unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) it into "bytes" and then use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function to get the bytes you need:

**test.php:**

```
<?php

$data = "Top Secret";
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, 'secret', true);

printf("%s\n", bin2hex($hash));

$byte_array = array_values(unpack('C*', $hash));

// print_r($byte_array);

print_r(array_slice($byte_array, 0, 4));
print_r(array_slice($byte_array, -4, 4));
```

**Test:**

```
$ php -f test.php
eb409b96bca8118b7e2067b9419d598d928f53251619665743980119de884bfb
Array
(
    [0] => 235
    [1] => 64
    [2] => 155
    [3] => 150
)
Array
(
    [0] => 222
    [1] => 136
    [2] => 75
    [3] => 251
)
```

Comment: thx , for your reply , but why you used (-4 , 4) ?

Comment: This is just another example to show that you can also get the last four bytes etc.

Comment: hi bro. can you help me in my new review?